# SQL Server : Output Control

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm having difficulties getting my head around the following problem.

I have a source table that looks like this:

Customers

```
Name   Hours   Job
--------------------
A      10      A01
A      05      A01
A      08      A01
NULL   NULL    NULL
B      10      B01
B      05      B01
B      08      B01
NULL   NULL    NULL
```

etc.

Basically the source table values are separated by NULLs when a new customer is reached.

What I need to do is create an output which is the same as the source table but with a few additions based on the Job number A01,B01,etc.

So it would look something like this:

```
Name   Hours   Job
--------------------
Tom
UK
A      10      A01
A      05      A01
A      08      A01
NULL   NULL    NULL
Ian
US
B      10      B01
B      05      B01
B      08      B01
NULL   NULL    NULL
```

Getting the country and name for each job number is easy enough, however, I have no idea how to incorporate them into the actual output of the query like it is shown above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you doing already? What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert blank row between groups of rows and sorted by ID in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517190/insert-blank-row-between-groups-of-rows-and-sorted-by-id-in-sql)

Comment: show the country  table structure

Comment: Does your table really contain NULL rows?

Comment: Checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7517437/932628) for adding rows between grouped data

Comment: @simsim OP table already look with null value now OP want to display country and name with that detail

Comment: @Sathish, same logic, in the post that I shared, instead of adding NULLs, he can add two rows, one from his country Table, and union another one from his table that he is using by selected distinct Name

Answer (score 0):

SQL is about getting the data out, not presenting it. I'd suggest you do that in your client code or stored procedure.

However, the way I've done this for demos etc is by unioning a load of stuff together with an order by column e.g.

```
select col1 from (
select 'a' as col1, 1 ord
union 
select null as col1, 2 ord
union 
select 'b' as col1, 3 ord
) tab
order by ord
```