# SQl Server SSIS DB mail: Put space between two rows in a table

Tags: html, ssis, sp-send-dbmail

I have a db mail setup in SQL Server to do the following table in the email:

```
FIle       XXX YYY ZZZ PPP

1404 0900   67  48  83  8
1404 1100   65  46  79  8
1404 1200   60  44  70  7
1404 1400   56  52  68  7
1404 1600   65  40  67  9
1404 1700   70  43  61  9

1504 0900   80  100 60  100 
1504 1100   80  100 60  100
```

How do i get the spaces between the 1404 and 1504 lines using the XML and HTML coding that db mail allows in the code?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: to restate: you have a table with the above data. A group may be defined by the first four characters of `FIle`. You would like to output data ordered by FIle and have a blank row inserted after each group?

Comment: Actually those groups are ddmm format

Comment: If possible I would like to put in the day corresponsing to the group in the blanks

Comment: Suspect the answer will be a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517190/insert-blank-row-between-groups-of-rows-and-sorted-by-id-in-sql/7517437#7517437 but I gotta get actual work done for a while

Comment: You could do this very easily in SSRS.

Comment: Hello Tab, I am interested in bilinkc's answer but I would also like to know more about the SSRS way of doing it? COuld you shed some light on the same? And can an SSRS output be sent by email in an SSIS task?

Answer (score 0):

User your SSRS to create a report output the content you desired. Deploy the report to your report server. In SSIS use a script task to call the SSRS report using URL method, save the report to local and send it out. Here is the details (I am using vb but you can use c# of course):

The URL to the report on report server: e.g.

http://XX.XX.XX.XX/ReportServer%2fSOMEREPORTFOLDER%2fSOMEREPORT&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL"

Note above rendering format is excel.

Then using following code in script task to save the report to your local network. Drivemappinguser and Drivermappingpassword are for accessing your ssrs server.

```
        Protected Sub SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String)

            Dim lorequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
            Dim loresponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
            Dim loresponsestream As System.IO.Stream
            Dim lofilestream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)


            Dim daUser As String

            daUser = Replace(Dts.Variables("DriveMappingUser").Value.ToString, "STORM\", "")



            Dim labytes(256) As Byte
            Dim licount As Integer = 1

            Try


                lorequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
                lorequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(daUser, Dts.Variables("DriveMappingPassword").Value.ToString, "Storm")

                ' lorequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

                lorequest.Timeout = 1000 * 90 * 30 'timeout 30 minutes
                lorequest.Method = "GET"
                loresponse = CType(lorequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
                loresponsestream = loresponse.GetResponseStream

                Do While licount > 0
                    licount = loresponsestream.Read(labytes, 0, 256)
                    lofilestream.Write(labytes, 0, licount)

                Loop

            lofilestream.Flush()
            lofilestream.Close()


            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(ex.Message)

            End Try



        End Sub
```

In your main method use this to call above method, url is the report url mentioned above, vFilePath is the path to the saved report.

```
            SaveFile(URL, vFilePath)
```

Then use this code in the script task to send out the email with the report attachment. str_SmtpClient is your smtp email server, str_UserName and str_Password is for accessing your smtp server.

```
        Protected Sub SendEmail(ByVal vFilePath As String)
            Dim preMon = MonthName(DatePart(DateInterval.Month, DateAdd("m", -1, Now))) + " " + CStr(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)))

            Dim strFrom As String = "ReportingServices@xxx.com"

            Dim strTo As String = Dts.Variables("RecipientEmail").Value.ToString

            Dim strSubject As String = "Some Reports " + preMon

            Dim strBody As String = "Dear " + Dts.Variables("RecipientName").Value.ToString + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Please find attached to this email your Partner Payment Report for the month of " + preMon + "." + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "To protect your confidentiality, the report has been password protected. The password will have already been issued to you previously, and will not be accompanied with this email. " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to get in contact with Mark Robertson, at mark.robertson@bcsg.com. " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Many thanks, " + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "Reporting Team"



            Dim msg As New MailMessage(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, strBody)

            msg.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(vFilePath))

            Dim client As New SmtpClient(Dts.Variables("str_SmtpClient").Value, 587)
            ' client.EnableSsl = True
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

            client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Dts.Variables("str_UserName").Value, Dts.Variables("str_Password").Value)
            client.Send(msg)

            Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)
        End Sub
```

Finally in your main method call above code

```
    SendEmail(vFilePath)
```