# Looping through a foreach and then grouping the data into date arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to loop through a foreach and group the result by date.

Example:

```
2017-10-05
2017-10-05

2017-10-07

2017-10-10
2017-10-10
2017-10-10
```

... and so on

As I don't know how to accomplish this I have only the standard code for a foreach to loop. I should point out the data is coming from an XML feed.

```
    foreach($streamData->channel->item as $item) {
        echo $item->date.'<br>';
    }
```

The code above prints the dates like this:

```
2017-10-05
2017-10-05
2017-10-07
2017-10-10
2017-10-10
2017-10-10
```

... and so on

How can I accomplish this as the example shows?

Comment: Is putting a blank line out when the date changes all you want to do?

Comment: No, well kind of. So the date is part of some events data. 

I have event name, team 1, team 2, date and a time. I basically want to display the date and then all the relevant events under that date. then move on to the next date and repeat

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517190/insert-blank-row-between-groups-of-rows-and-sorted-by-id-in-sql

Comment: Who ever posted an then deleted their answer that worked! I basically just set the current date as a variable and check that against the next one to see if it matched

Comment: I believe that was @RiggsFolly

Comment: ok, I undeleted it. Was not sure it fitted you requirement and had to go to a quick meeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is decide when to do the event processing then this is the sort of construct you might use.

```
$last_date = null;
foreach($streamData->channel->item as $item) {
    if ( $last_date != $item->date ) {
        echo '<br>' . $item->date . '<br>';
    }

    $last_date = $item->date;
    // do event processing
}
```

How accurate this might be depends upon where you get your event information from.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have any object data to test on I'm not sure it works but maybe..

> Edit I tested on an array and it seems I was wrong. Here is what does work on an array;
>   https://3v4l.org/VSJeQ
>   I think I matched your object with this array.

```
foreach($streamData->channel->item as $item) {
    echo item->date.'<br>';
    if(next($streamData)->date != $item->date) echo '<br>';
}
```

Basically use next() to see if the next item is not the same as the current. If it's true add another `<br>`

Edit; it may need to be changed to next($item) instead of next($item->date) now that I think about it

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution would be to create a map, and store each grouping of dates as members of the map. The values of those members would be the array of dates, accessible in constant time O(1) by the date month key, which requires no loops later on when you want to search the groups or something like that.

For instance, this is the JSON representation of what I am thinking:

```
{
    "10": [
        "2017-10-10",
        "2017-10-10",
        "2017-10-10",
    ],
    "9": [
        "2017-10-9",
        "2017-10-9",
        "2017-10-9",
    ],
    // ...
}
```

Now you can simply do a loop like "for each group of this object", and then "for each date of this group".